# Why can i change an implementation of property defined in interface in the class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

I am trying to understand that if I create an interface ITest which defines one property Version with only getter in it. Then when I implement this interface in Test class I can change the definition of the property to getter and setter. How can i change the implementation of an interface as shown below?

```
internal interface ITest
    {
         int MyProperty { get;}
        void changeValue();
    }




   public class Test : ITest
    {
        public int MyProperty
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void changeValue()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're still honouring the interface - you have a property getter. The interface does not preclude you adding a setter as well.

Comment: Why? How?  What is the question?

Comment: I agree with Blam, your question is unclear. [Could you try to clarify it a bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30530937/edit)

Comment: @Rob I am getting it what you want to say. It means that we are implementing getter and even kind of overriding the implementation with setter. That is why it works. Am I correct?

Comment: @Balraj I added an answer to try to explain further.

Comment: Interfaces define what you **must have**, not what you **can have**. If interfaces were this restrictive, then your class would **only** be able to have methods defined in the interfaces and you wouldn't be able to create your own methods or properties unless they were in the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
interface ITest2
{
     int MyProperty_Get();
}
```

It's not a surprise that you can implement this interface with this class

```
class Test2 : ITest2
{
    private int myProperty;
    public int MyProperty_Get()
    {
         return myProperty;
    }

    //Not in the interface..
    public void MyProperty_Set(int value)  
    {
         myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

You can add a `set` function to your class implementation, even though no `set` function is defined in the interface. The compiler doesn't object. That's exactly what you're doing in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value within a class you should add private setter:

```
internal interface ITest
{
     int MyProperty { get;}
     void ChangeValue();
}

class MyClass : ITest
{
    public int MyProperty { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeValue()
    {
        MyProperty = 1;
    }
}
```

*Remember that:*

Interface member:

```
int Property { get; }
```

is correct for implementation:

```
public int Property { get; private set;}
```

or

```
public int Property
{ 
    get
    { 
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**You can not change the behaviour of interface members. It's a contract which class must follow.**

Comment: But my question is that I should not be able to change the definition provided  by interface. Compiler should give an error. But that is not the case. Why so?

Comment: The setter doesn't have to be private. Your class could still go beyond the definition of the interface, and that implementation could provide a public setter as well. The only reason you want to keep the setter private is if you don't want it to be writable from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

If youre doing something like

```
ITest test = new Test();
```

You will not be able to access the setter publicly. If you only want to access the setter privately you can use:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void changeValue(int value)
    {
        MyProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All an interface does is declare the **bare minimum** that any implementing class will do. It is a contract that "every type that implements this interface will have these properties and methods." It does **not** at all limit the implementing class to *only* the methods and properties defined on an interface.

For example, if you have a class that implements `IDisposable`, do you expect that class to have no other functionality than a `Dispose()` method?

What happens is that the interface defines what you can do with an object when you utilize it as an interface instead of the concrete type:

```
public int CountItems(IEnumerable<int> items)
{
    return items.Count();
}
```

The above is a very simplistic example, but is enough to illustrate this point. That method can be called with both of the following calls:

```
CountItems(new [] {1, 2, 3});
CountItems(new List<int> {1, 2, 3});
```

All the internal method cares about is whether or not the objects being sent to it expose the Linq method `Count()` which is found on `IEnumerable<T>`.

So with your example interface, all you're saying is that "if you operate on this interface, all you're ever going to be able to do is to get the value of `MyProperty`."

Therefore, all of these classes will be valid:

```
public void Test1 : ITest
{
    public int MyProperty { get; private set; }

    public void changeValue() 
    {
        this.MyProperty = 12;
    }
}

public void Test2 : ITest
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public void changeValue()
    {
        this.MyProperty = 9;
    }
}
```

If the operation that you're trying to do needs to set that value without the method, then you're going to have to either restrict that operation to only work on `Test2`, or rework the interface. But if you don't need to use the setter, then the lack of one on the interface is fine for that definition.